# What is the maximum value of a Float32Array?

Tags: javascript

I need to signify that some of the indices in my array are 'empty'. I don't want to use another array to do this and cannot use 0 or anything near it since they will be common as legitimate values in the array.

I don't expect large values to ever occur in the array and it just so happens that having a very large value to signify emptyness would double as a speedhack as I do a threshold comparison as the first check for further processing and inherently huge values would get eliminated by this as well.

Anyways, I cant find the equivalent of Number.MAX_VALUE for a Float32Array, I'm also not sure if its implementation specific. Whereas technically I can just use any large value, having the maximum value would give me some odd satisfaction.

How do I find out the maximum value that goes into a Float32Array?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured out I can use Infinity and it works out just great. Still keeping this out of curiosity though.

Comment: The idiomatic value would be undefined not Infinity.

Comment: @AluanHaddad read the post before commenting please